# Ubuntu 20.10. Streaks across screen, video example in description

Tags: update-manager, 20.10, gpu, gpu-driver

Following a software update that required a restart, my laptop has strange streaks across the screen. It is more prominent in more conditions than other as demonstrated in the video. I have been told that i might need to restart my GPU drivers. Do u agree? If so, how do i restart it and check what kind of GPU i have.

This issue appeared after one of those software updates that require restarting, it is not a problem i have had before and more or less appeared out of the blue.

I know there isnt a lot of info here as i am a ubuntu noob. I will provide any additional info in the comments, just let me know how to get the info and i will be on the case. If you know what is going on and how to fix it please let me know. Thanks

Video:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FH8D14ps0FixGPV0FWa6ukHC4corTKit/view][1]

Edit:
so i tried uninstalling and reinstalling gpu drivers (sorry if these are the wrong terms) with:

sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel

unfortunately still having isues

Comment: "I will provide any additional info in the comments" Any further information should not be added to the comment trail but added to your question as an [edit]. Comments are our way of asking you questions.